# Stuck At Deletion of li elements through Filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to delete li element when user click on 'Done' button I'm stuck at How I can pass an id to my `deleteItems` function so I can filter, I used Key to do it didn't work for me

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'
import ListItems from '../Components/ListItems'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state={
      List: [],
      addFeild: ''
    }
  }

addFeildChange=(event)=>{
  let value= event.target.value
  console.log(value)
  this.setState({
    addFeild: value
  })
}

addtoList=()=>{
  this.setState({
    List: this.state.List.concat(this.state.addFeild)
  })
}

deleteItems=()=>{
 console.log("Done Clicked ")
// const Filtered=this.state.List.filter(item=>{
//   return item!==key;
// })
// this.setState({
//   List: Filtered
// })

}


render(){
  return(
    <div>
  <ListItems deleteItems={this.deleteItems} addtoList={this.addtoList}List={this.state.List} addFeildChange={this.addFeildChange}/>
    </div>
    );
  } 
}

  
 
export default App;
```

ListItems.js

```
import React from 'react'

const ListItems=(props)=>{
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>To-do</h1>
            <input onChange={props.addFeildChange} type='text' placeholder='Add here'/>
            <button onClick={props.addtoList}>Add</button>
            <ul>
                {props.List.map((item, index)=>{
                    return <li key={index}> {item}  <button onClick={props.deleteItems}>Done</button></li> 
                })} 
            </ul>

        </div>
        );
}


export default ListItems
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update your `delelteItems` function with this

```
deleteItems = itemToRemove => {
    const { List } = this.state;
    const newList = List.filter(item => item !== itemToRemove);
    this.setState({
      List: newList
    });
  };
```

and pass item reference from list component like this

```
 <button onClick={() => props.deleteItems(item)}>Done</button>
```

You can check this also
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xugsaz?file=src%2FListItems.js